# How to build the project to specific folder with visual studio command line tools?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, cl

I've got this simplified folders structure for c++ project named project_name.

```
project_name
    -build
    -headers
    -sources 
    -resources
```

If I do `cl /EHsc /W4 sources/source1.cpp sources/source2.cpp /link /out:project_name ...` it creates build files in current directory only which is project_name, resulting this:

```
project_name
    -build
    -headers
    -sources 
    -resources
     project_name.exe         
     source1.obj
     source2.obj
     etc
```

What I want is to specify the folder where all the build files have to be placed, in my case in a `build` folder.

What options are needed for `cl` or `link` to do that that from `project_name` directory ?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx) and especially [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx) arcticles?

Comment: @mvidelgauz what's the reason for downvoting my question ?? Yes I did read those articles

Comment: The reason downvoting in this case is _"question does not show any research effort"_. I think those articles (found in few seconds) clearly answer your question

Comment: @mvidelgauz you are wroung, if they answer my question I woudn't have posted it here on so. The research effort can be achieved by thinking of a solution to my problem

Comment: You specified output for linker only, but not for `cl` - that's why .obj files are in root. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb8e9b8y.aspx). And for other output files read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1cb223a.aspx)

Comment: @mvidelgauz That is the *actual* answer to this question; you should post it as one.

Comment: @CodyGray The answer given by yngum is better (that's me who upvoted it) if we think about ***actual solution for the problem***. My answer is more formal and more to explain OP why I downvoted this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `.bat` file in your project directory and use that to build your project.

```
pushd %~dp0/build
cl %~dp0/sources/source1.cpp %~dp0/sources/source2.cpp
popd
```

`%~dp0` automatically expands to full path of your project directory so you can execute this `.bat` file from anywhere.